How to get difference based from the previous instance?
Currently working on a sheet that continuously adds items with value daily.
How do I automate in getting the difference between one value to it's corresponding previous value from the day before? The Days and Items increase periodically and sometimes the number of items don't change. Been trying to figure out a way to automatically get the difference.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/101qXt381UPcuSusRMCOjBnx1P9lvHuSitrSwdFJEvz0/edit?gid=0#gid=0
I tried using arrays but can't seem to get the formula working.

Consider providing input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Click here to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

You can try this formula:
=ArrayFormula(LET(dates,A2:A23,
              id,B2:B23,
              vals,C2:C23,
              prevDates,dates-1,
              lookupId,id&TEXT(dates,"mm-dd-yyyy"),
              searchId,id&TEXT(prevDates,"mm-dd-yyyy"),
              searchPrev,IFNA(VLOOKUP(searchId,SORT(HSTACK(lookupId,vals,dates,id),1,TRUE),{2,3,4},TRUE),),
              diff,IF((CHOOSECOLS(searchPrev,2)=prevDates)*(CHOOSECOLS(searchPrev,3)=id),vals-CHOOSECOLS(searchPrev,1),vals),
              diff))


If you want to return empty when the item is not found in the previous day, you can adjust the formula into this:
=ArrayFormula(LET(dates,A2:A23,
              id,B2:B23,
              vals,C2:C23,
              prevDates,dates-1,
              lookupId,id&TEXT(dates,"mm-dd-yyyy"),
              searchId,id&TEXT(prevDates,"mm-dd-yyyy"),
              searchPrev,IFNA(VLOOKUP(searchId,SORT(HSTACK(lookupId,vals,dates,id),1,TRUE),{2,3,4},TRUE),),
              diff,IF((CHOOSECOLS(searchPrev,2)=prevDates)*(CHOOSECOLS(searchPrev,3)=id),vals-CHOOSECOLS(searchPrev,1),),
              diff))



Use reverse search of XLOOKUP by getting various OFFSETs from the first item to the current row:
=LET(
  firstItm, B1,
  itemRg, B2:B23, 
  BYROW(itemRg,
   LAMBDA(r,
    LET(
      sRg, OFFSET(r,-1,0):firstItm, 
      valueRg, OFFSET(r,0,1), 
      valueRg-XLOOKUP(r, sRg, OFFSET(sRg,0,1),NA(),0,-1)))))


You can use the following formula in cell D2:
=IFNA(MAP(B2:B,C2:C,LAMBDA(
   β,γ,IF(ROW(β)=2,,
     γ-XLOOKUP(β,
         B2:OFFSET(β,-1,),
         C2:OFFSET(γ,-1,),
         #N/A,,-1))))) 


Use Filter
You may use the filter function to get the specific values to be subtracted (based on the dates and identifier). You may use the following formula:
=LET(a,ARRAYFORMULA(A2:C23),b,INDEX(a,,1),c,INDEX(a,,2),d,INDEX(a,,3),e,BYROW(a,LAMBDA(x,TRANSPOSE(INDEX(FILTER(a,b=INDEX(x,,1)-1,c=INDEX(x,,2)),,3)))),arrayformula(iferror(d-e,"NO PREVIOUS DATA")))

Output:

I added a "NO PREVIOUS DATA" for error catching to indicate the absence of data from the previous day.

I wondered if it could be done done without lookups or lambdas? The answer is 'yes' but it's a bit long.
The method uses sort, offset by a row, find difference and sort back.
=ArrayFormula(let(data,{A2:C,row(A2:C)},
sdata,sort(data,2,true,1,true),
odata,vstack({"","","",""},
chooserows(sdata,sequence(rows(sdata)-1))),
diff,if(choosecols(sdata,1)="","",if(choosecols(sdata,2)<>choosecols(odata,2),"",choosecols(sdata,3)-choosecols(odata,3))),
sort(diff,choosecols(sdata,4),true)))


